# Deploy local Vueapp on server

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i am trying to export the Vueapp which is on local server to web server , but not able to find certain correct steps to do it so.

Can we export it ?

Comment: Run `npm run build` for building the app, then you have a normal html page with a bunch of js you can deploy like every other webpage

Comment: Do i need to run npm run build in local or in server cmd ?

Comment: where you have the vue project, then you can transfer the output to your server

Comment: Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 16548ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    build.js  2.15 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
build.js.map  9.74 MB       0  [emitted]         main

Comment: This comes up after running the above cmd into project folder

Comment: can you please guide me through the next step to get in to live ?

Comment: You should view a folder called "dist", the content of that folder is what you can upload to your server

Comment: But that contains two js files only ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ?

Comment: Generally the dist folder contains an index.html file, a js folder and a css folder

Comment: my dist folder contains - two files (build.js and build.js.map) & one other file index.html created

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: try uploading and testing that files, maybe they are enough for your project if they are the only output of the build process

Comment: Ok , after uploading those file  , whats the next step ?

Comment: Do i need to execute commands on server ?

Comment: If it is setted to serve static files (for example it has apache installed) you have nothing to do aside of opening the server domain in a browser ("http://your.site.com")